# Proof about open balls and Cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Hi I try to proof this $$B((a,b),r)\subset B\left(a,\frac{r}{2}\right)×B\left(b,\frac{r}{2}\right)$$ this is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$,I try taking $(x,y) \in B((a,b),r)$ by definition

$|(x,y)-(a,b)|<r$

$|(x-a,0)+(0,y-b)|<r$

By triangular inequality
$|(x-a,0)+(0,y-b)|<|(x-a,0)|+|(0,y-b)|$

I thing this is equal to
$|(x-a,0)|+|(0,y-b)|=|x-a|+|y-b|$

In particular if

$|x-a|<\frac{r}{2}$ and $|y-b|<\frac{r}{2}$

Is that correct?

Comment: You would have hard time proving this, since this is false. The opposite inclusion is true.

Comment: Really and if y change $r/2$ with $r$ is true or in general is the opposite Inclusion  true ?

Comment: For $r$ in place of $r/2$ this is true, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Try to draw it in an easy case (for example $n = m = 1$, $a = b = 0, r = 1$).

You will se that $B(a, r/2) \times B(b, r/2)$ is a small open square strictly contained in the ball $B((a,b), r)$. In particular, the square is  $(-1/2, 1/2) \times (-1/2, 1/2)$, which is clearly strictly contained in the circle of radius $1$ and center $(0,0)$. For instance, the vertices of the square are contained in the ball but not in the open square.

With the same idea you can prove that the general case is not true.

On the other hand, what is actually true is the opposite direction $B((a,b), r) \supset B(a, r/2) \times B(b, r/2)$ as well as the inclusion $B((a,b), r) \subset B(a, r) \times B(b, r)$.